# Consistency of a System of linear equations using unknowns in the matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Can anyone tell me how would I answer these type of questions?
I already know how to answer the normal way which doesn't include any variables such as Alpha in the question.

[image]

Comment: So, how would you go about solving these problems without the variable $\alpha$?

Comment: I would reduce the matrix to row echelon form and then check consistency, whether there is a row of zeros or not would make me determine consistency.

Comment: OK, have you tried doing that here?

Comment: I am not able to compute the row echelon form because of the existence of **α**. Could you please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed via row-reduction, just as you would without the variable. Taking the first problem, subtract 3 times the first row from the second to get $$\begin{bmatrix}1&\alpha&4\\0&6-3\alpha&-4\end{bmatrix}.$$ Examine the last row of this matrix. If $6-3\alpha=0$, the pivot will be in the third column, and you’ll end up with an inconsistent system. If $6-3\alpha\ne0$, you can proceed with the reduction to row-ecehlon form, but the lower-right element will remain non-zero, so the system is consistent in the case. Can you solve the other problem yourself now?

Comment: Yes now I can, the solution of the second one is **R** , Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @AhmedAsaad Are you sure about that? I get the condition $2a+4=0$ for consistency.